# Соединение из Docker контейнера по ssh всегда требует пароль пользователя удаленного хоста

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, docker

Хочу из контейнера *(rails из докер хаба и то что он поддерживается не проблема)* зайти по ssh на VPS *(Digital Ocean)* и не могу сбросить запрос пароля.

Пробовал по разному
Просто закинул ключ из контейнера на VPS (ssh-copy-id -i ~/.ssh/new.pub ...).
При последующих соединениях запрашивает пароль

Генерирую на контейнере пару ключей и копирую их на ХОСТ систему.
С которой закидываю публичный ключ контейнера в authorized_keys VPS.
Все равно запрашивает пароль при каждом соединении из контейнера.

Для хост машины только подтверждение на добавление в авторизированные.

PS Вывод с опцией *-v*

```
OpenSSH_6.7p1 Debian-5+deb8u3, OpenSSL 1.0.1t  3 May 2016
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to xx.xxx.xxx.xxx [xx.xxx.xxx.xxx] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: permanently_set_uid: 0/0
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.7p1 Debian-5+deb8u3
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.1
debug1: match: OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.1 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr umac-64-etm@openssh.com none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr umac-64-etm@openssh.com none
debug1: sending SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_INIT
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ECDSA  ...
debug1: Host 'xx.xxx.xxx.xxx' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /root/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /root/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Trying private key: /root/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Trying private key: /root/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Trying private key: /root/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug1: Next authentication method: password
```

PS 2 Соединение с указанием конкретного ключа

```
ssh -v -i ~/.ssh/next.pub root@xx.xx1.xx6.xx3
OpenSSH_6.7p1 Debian-5+deb8u3, OpenSSL 1.0.1t  3 May 2016
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to xx.xx1.xx6.xx3 [xx.xx1.xx6.xx3] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: permanently_set_uid: 0/0
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/next.pub type 1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/next.pub-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.7p1 Debian-5+deb8u3
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.1
debug1: match: OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.1 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr umac-64-etm@openssh.com none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr umac-64-etm@openssh.com none
debug1: sending SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_INIT
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ECDSA ....
debug1: Host 'xx.xx1.xx6.xx3' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /root/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /root/.ssh/next.pub
debug1: Server accepts key: pkalg ssh-rsa blen 279
debug1: key_load_private_type: incorrect passphrase supplied to decrypt private key
Enter passphrase for key '/root/.ssh/next.pub': 
debug1: Next authentication method: password
root@xx.xx1.xx6.xx3's password:
```

Comment: добавьте ключ -v и посмотрите как происходит аутентификация

Comment: каждый раз или каждый раз после рестарта контейнера?

Comment: каждый раз (контейнеры пока не перезагружаю и не сохраняю в них изменений - застрял на этой проблеме и пока они у меня каждый раз из образа создаются) @KoVadim

Comment: @MikhailVaysman Добавил вывод в тело вопроса

Comment: "контейнеры пока не перезагружаю и не сохраняю в них изменений" "пока они у меня каждый раз из образа создаются" - не находите это противоречивым? судя по логу - ни один файл с ключем не подошел. То есть, как раз то, что я и думаю - каждый раз, когда Вы пытаетесь сделать подключение - у Вас новый контейнер.

Comment: @KoVadim нет, все в одной "сессии"
`docker run -it -v path/:path rails /bin/bash`
как запускаю контейнер так из него не выхожу

Comment: Вы пишете, что забрасываете ключ  ~/.ssh/new.pub , а судя по логу, оно его даже и не пробует. Может попросить явно? `ssh -i  ~/.ssh/new.pub ....`. Если это отработает - тогда можно поправить будет ssh конфиг.

Comment: @KoVadim, добавил вывод по соединению с указанием конкретного ключа

Comment: Так new или next? И ключ запаролен:)

Comment: @KoVadim
**создаю ключ**
`ssh-keygen -b 2048 -t rsa -f ~/.ssh/sss -q -N ''`

**копирую его на хост машину и с нее кидаю на VPS**
`cat path/sss.pub | ssh root@xx.xx1.xx6.xx3 'cat >> .ssh/authorized_keys && echo "Key copied"`
**перезагружаю на sshd на VPS **
`service sshd restart`
**соединяюсь**
    ...
    debug1: Server accepts key: pkalg ssh-rsa blen 279
    debug1: key_load_private_type: incorrect passphrase supplied to decrypt private key
    Enter passphrase for key '/root/.ssh/sss.pub': 
    debug1: Next authentication method: password
    root@xx.xx1.xxx.xxx's password:

Comment: есть подозрение, что ключ "ломается" при копировании. То есть, на серверной стороне, в файле authorized_keys ключи лежат не каждый в своей строке, а скопом.

Comment: @KoVadim 
но такой способ 
[https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-ssh-key-based-authentication-on-a-linux-server](описан даже в доках провайдера)

Comment: А если там будет написано "прыгайте с обрыва", Вы пригните? или жалобу в Роскомнадзор напишете? Документацию пишут тоже люди и они не могут отследить все случаи.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Чтобы все было по правилам отвечу сам.
У в той ситуации было несколько проблем.

1. у службы sshd на сервере на был установлен **PasswordAuthentication yes**
2. Иногда у меня с агентом что-то происходило и он ключ не подгружал.

Answer (score 2):

> `ssh -i ~/.ssh/next.pub ...`

судя по имени файла, вы пытаетесь указать программе *ssh*, чтобы она использовала для аутентификации **публичную** часть ключа, в то время как указывать надо **секретную**. которая, скорее всего, содержится в файле `~/.ssh/next`:

```
$ ssh -i ~/.ssh/next ...
```